# How can I check if there was a redirection on another controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-redirect

I am redirecting from a controller to another one.

```
redirect_to :controller => :controller_name, :action => :action_name
```

Then on the action I want to check if there was a redirection

```
def action_name
  #check if there wass redirected
end
```

Comment: Why does it matter?  They landed in that specific controller; what actions do you need to take that distinguish their flow from someone that landed there intentionally?

Comment: I want to take diferent action when the user redirected on the action_name controller from when he visits the actual controller directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way is as described by @Dimitris in another answer how it could also be done like this

```
if some_condition
  flash[:redirect] = 'some value'
  redirect_to :controller => :controller_name, :action => :action_name
end
```

and in another controller `controller_name`

```
def action_name
  if flash[:redirect] == 'value you set' # checks if came from redirection
    # your intended code here
  end
end
```

> As values stored in **flash** hash persist over single redirection  you can do like this however beware of **flash.now** as it only persist over that request only, after the request is responded **flash.now** values are flushed.
>   However you can make persist **key: values** persistent as much as you like. For more info read 
>   this.http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash

Or Simply you could use `Session`  instead of `flash` but you have to clear the `session` your self after job is done. At the end of the day, `flash` is also stored in the `session`

Answer (score 1):

You can always perform a specific check on the referer like:

```
if request.referer =~ /controller-name-here/
  # code here
end
```

Comment: This is close but didn't solve my problem, I need to find out if there was a redirection.